"Missing required prop" while passing data from blade to vue
I am new in vue and laravel.
I am trying to pass on a data to vue from blade. I am sure I am mising something very simple, but cant see it.
app.js
import "./bootstrap";

import { createApp } from "vue";
import releases from "./vue/Releases.vue";
createApp(releases).mount("#v-releases");

index.blade.php
<x-layout.basic>
    <div id="v-releases" userData="1"></div>
</x-layout.basic>

for index.blade.php, I also tried
<x-layout.basic>
    <div id="v-releases" :userData="1"></div>
</x-layout.basic>

Releases.vue
<template>
  <div>userIsAdmin: {{ userIsAdmin }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { computed } from 'vue';

  const props = defineProps({
    userData: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  });

  const userIsAdmin = computed(() => props.userData === 1);
  console.log('User data:', props.userData);
</script>

Result: userIsAdmin: false where it should be true.
And on console: Missing required prop: "userData"
What am I missing???
I expect userIsAdmin: true

What is <div id="v-releases">? Where is your Releases.vue component? There is nothing magic here, you need to call the Vue component here and pass it :userData="1" to have the number.

I think you are mounting a vue app on the #v-releases element, but that's not in the vue context yet. You have to mount your app first, and in it you should place the releases component.

Oh yes, you're right. Here is an example where you can set HTML and see how it is supposed to look. https://vuejs.org/examples/#simple-component


The prop should be in kebab-case.
Thanks @user3791775!
Changed app.js to
import { createApp } from "vue";

import releases from "./vue/Releases.vue";
const appElement = document.getElementById("v-releases");
const userData = appElement.getAttribute("userData");
createApp(releases, { userData: Number(userData) }).mount("#v-releases");

And it works! Could you please pass you comment as response so I can accept? (that's how it works, righgt? sorry, new in stockoverflow as well :))

That is also true, Vue might fix it by itself but this is indeed how it is supposed to be.

If I may add another question here - is my approach correct? ie: passing data blade-vue?

This is a simple example so nothing is wrong with it yes.
